# how to list top 3 maximum values and a corresponding cell name

Tags: excel

I have spreadsheet that collects players scores for various events and sums their total scores.

I have teams 1-8 in cells D3:K3 and the totals in cells D12:K12.

How can I get the top 3 scores and list them alongside the corresponding team?

Comment: What should happen if there is a tie? Say the 3rd and 4th team score equally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way will work to get the correct team names *even if you have duplicate scores*:

Use this formula in M2 copied down to get the top scores

`=LARGE(D$12:K$12,ROWS(M$2:M2))`

and then this formula in N2

`=INDEX(D$3:K$3,SMALL(IF(D$12:K$12=M2,COLUMN(D$12:K$12)-COLUMN(D$12)+1),COUNTIF(M$2:M2,M2)))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> and then also copied down

You can use this for top 3 or to list all the scores and teams in order

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you!! (sorry for the late response - I've been busy with other things! )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about listing the top three "alongside" the corresponding team, but you can use `=Large(D$4:D$11,1)` to find the top value, `=Large(D$4:D$11,2)` to find the second highest value, and `=Large(D$4:D$11,3)` to find the third highest value.

You can also find the row number using Match. `=MATCH(D14,D$4:D$11,0)+3`